# Why my masked entry won't update but everything else does (xamarin.forms.MaskedEntry control)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently i am saving data from a form which has a MaskedEntry, saving it for the first time works. My problem is that when i click on the details page and try to update it, everything updates but NOT my MaskedEntry. Before that i tried without using a MaskedEntry and it was working.

In the debuger on  `await App.Database.UpdateTasksAsync(task);` you can see that everything change except the TaskDuration which is the MaskedEntry.

Before date i was using this instead of MaskedEntry and i had no problem but ofcourse it's not masked.

```
<Entry x:Name="TaskDuration" Placeholder="HH:MM:SS" Text="{Binding TaskDuration}"/>
```

**Note:** I have many entries already for TasksGroup and Tasks and they all work except for the MaskedEntry for Tasks when updated.

i used : https://github.com/TBertuzzi/Xamarin.Forms.MaskedEntry

Thanks for help.

**1. Fill the initial form from NewTasksGroupPage.xaml ( this one is saved once and it works)**

```
//other entry fields
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Durée quotidienne" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>

                <control:MaskedEntry Placeholder="HH:MM:SS" Mask="XX:XX:XX" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding TaskDuration}"></control:MaskedEntry>
                <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessages[TaskDuration]}" TextColor="#FF0000" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
```

**2. Saving the initial form in NewTaskPageViewModel.cs**

```
 async Task SaveNewTask()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Task.Delay(4000);


            IsBusy = false;

            TasksGroup tasksGroup = new TasksGroup();
            Tasks tasks = new Tasks();

            tasksGroup.TasksGroupDescription = TasksGroupDescription;
            tasksGroup.TasksGroupDate = TasksGroupDate;
            tasks.TaskDuration = TaskDuration;
            tasks.TaskDBA = TaskDBA;
            tasks.TaskDescription = TaskDescription;

            tasksGroup.Taches = new List<Tasks>() { tasks };


            if(ValidateTasksGroup(tasksGroup) && ValidateTasks(tasks))
            {

                await App.Database.SaveTasksGroupAsync(tasksGroup);
                //tasks.TasksGroupID = tasksGroup.ID;
                //await App.Database.AddTaskAsync(tasks);

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                

                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }


        }
```

**3. Editing the entries from the TasksDetailsPage.xaml (that's the one that doesn't update)**

```
//other entries
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Durée quotidienne" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
                <control:MaskedEntry Placeholder="HH:MM:SS" Mask="XX:XX:XX" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding TaskDuration}"></control:MaskedEntry>
                <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessages[TaskDuration]}" TextColor="#FF0000" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
```

**4. Updating the details page from TasksDetailsPageViewModel.cs**

```
async Task UpdateTask(TasksGroup tasksGroup, Tasks task)
{

    if (ValidateTasksGroup(tasksGroup) && ValidateTasks(task))
    {
        bool isUserAccept = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Update", "Voulez-vous vraiment modifier les informations", "OK", "Cancel");
        if (isUserAccept)
        {

            await App.Database.UpdateTasksGroupAsync(tasksGroup);
            await App.Database.UpdateTasksAsync(task);

        }

        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: MaskedEntry is not a standard XF control.  Where are you getting this from?

Comment: edited with the link in the post : https://github.com/TBertuzzi/Xamarin.Forms.MaskedEntry

Comment: where is `TaskDuration` defined?  Where is it updated?  What value is it being updated with?  Is the problem that the new value is NOT being saved to the db?  Or that the new value is not updated in the UI?

Comment: It was working with a normal entry before. All i did is change it to use the control

Comment: @Jason with a normal entry the value was being saved to the db but as soon as i use MaskedEntry control for my details page, it doesn't update to new value it only keeps the first value saved. Which is weird because it works when saving for the first time but not updating.

Comment: you need to debug it.  Is the model getting the correct value from the entry?  Is the db updating with the correct value from the model?  This is a multi-step process, you need to determine which step is causing the problem.

Comment: @Jason If it worked with this before : <Entry x:Name="TaskDuration" Placeholder="HH:MM:SS" Text="{Binding TaskDuration}"/> isn't it just a control issue ?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm just suggesting you spend the time debugging the code instead of making assumptions about what the problem may be.

Comment: @codetime Does it update for `Entry`? If yes, check the MaskedEntry control.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Yes it updates for the entry. Which is weird because when i save data for the first time, it saves the MaskedEntry correctly. But when i update the data, only the masked entry doesn't update. But if i use a normal entry instead of masked, it will work.